# Regex to find two identical strings within a string in python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Say I have a string like:

```
..."StringToMatch":{"id":"StringToMatch","This":"SomeRandomThing"...
```

Well, it's actually a JSON but I want to treat it like a string for other reasons. How would I find the `StringToMatch` using regular expressions?

I'm currently using:

```
value1, value2 = re.findall('"(.*?)":{"id":"(.*?)","This":"SomeRandomThing"', string)[0][:2]
if value1 == value2:
    return value1
```

But it seems a bit of a "hacky" way of doing it. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```py
"(\w+)":{"id":"\1"
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/jD7Kdg/2/).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ":{"id":"                '":{"id":"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \1                       what was matched by capture \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
```

**[Python code example](https://tio.run/##ZY6xCsIwEIb3PEW4pQmWQHEr@Ag6aMeAlHomGZqE5ETFh49pi5O3HNz/cd8f32SD35fi5hgS8YQsocEXP/DUgNDPnYT@A@4GPegOGkaY6ZopVQCUUhoulJw3QziONFldYV3puv@SVsNgXd6iMON59Lcw15M3enkFbF7AxYwq45gmK9YuLf9JJXN3vlEucx@In4LHnvE6scpIrKEyKTyi6KQs5Qs)**:

```py
import re
regex = r'"(\w+)":{"id":"\1"'
test_str = "...\"StringToMatch\":{\"id\":\"StringToMatch\",\"This\":\"SomeRandomThing\"..."
match = re.search(regex, test_str)
if match is not None:
    print(match.group(1))
```